# Guarding against a switch button having a nil optional value

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, optional-binding

I have a piece of code that runs if a switch has been set in settings as follows:

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "signatureSwitchState")

        let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "signatureSwitchState") as! Bool

        if buttonState == true {

            sign()

        }
```

My problem is if the switch has never been activated the program fails as the compiler states that, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

My question is then how best to guard against a nil value when using a bool such as the switch in the above statement.

I've tried if let statements and guard statements but the compiler complains that these cannot be used with a bool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "signatureSwitchState")
```

If the value is not explicitly set, it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get a bool from the UserDefaults you can use

`let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "signatureSwitchState")`,

this function returns a Bool so you know that the value can only be true or false and if it doesn't find a value for the key then it will return false. The function you are using

`UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "signatureSwitchState")`

returns a AnyObject? so it can be nil.

Answer (score 1):

Little known, but highly recommended by Apple:

Register defaults values which are considered until the user changes the value the first time.

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` – at least before accessing the value the first time – register the key / value pair(s).

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValues : [String : Any] = ["signatureSwitchState" : false]
userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

Now the value is never `nil` (I know the `Bool` example is pretty weak)

```
let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "signatureSwitchState")
```

The objects take much more advantage of that way than the "primitive" types which are never `nil` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do this. Since this is a bool, it's probably easiest just to use nil-coalescing `??`:

```
let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "signatureSwitchState") as? Bool ?? false
```

Or, you could use `guard` to do it, which is probably more robust:

```
guard let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "signatureSwitchState") as? Bool else { return }
if buttonState == true {
    sign()
}
```

Note that in both cases, you have to change the forced unwrap (`!`) to an optional unwrap (`?`).

Answer (score 0):

I have a tip that might come in useful in the future, though it's not as good as[picciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600753/picciano)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39580788/3141234) which is definitely the correct way to go.

`UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "signatureSwitchState")` returns an `AnyObject`.

If you try to force cast to `Bool` (`as! Bool`), this will crash if the returned value isn't a `Bool`, or if it is `nil`. Instead, if you conditionally cast (`as? Bool`), you'll receive a `Bool?`. This will cast the value to a `Bool` if it exists, otherwise it'll give you `nil` (without crashing.

From there, you can convert this `Bool?` to `Bool` by using the nil coalescing operator (`??`). It will return you the `Bool` value if there is one, otherwise it'll return the default value you give it. In this case, `false`.

Also, because `buttonState` is already a `Bool`, there's no reason to compare it to `true` in your `if` statement. Just use it directly:

```
let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "signatureSwitchState") as? Bool ?? false
if buttonState {
    sign()
}
```